# Is it possible to only display custom premissions in django admin?

Tags: django

I want to display only custom permissions (which I have created with Meta class in Model) in Django admin interface. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider creating your own custom view to add the custom permissions, instead of trying to modify the Django admin. However, if you're sure you want to use the Django admin, you could try the following approach:

Start by subclass `UserChangeForm`, and override the `__init__` method. Set `self.fields['user_permissions'].queryset` with a queryset containing your custom permissions.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        custom_permissions = ????
        self.fields['user_permissions'].queryset = custom_permissions
```

Next, subclass `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`, and use your form instead of the `UserChangeForm`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
```

Finally, unregister the default `UserAdmin`, and register your own.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I would do it with custom view as you suggest, tnx.